# Python Pandas: create variable for unique combinations of 2 categorical variables?

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

Say I have some data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'location':['store','online','store','online','online'],
                  'item': ['apple','apple','orange','orange','orange']})
df
>>>

location    item
0   store   apple
1   online  apple
2   store   orange
3   online  orange
4   online  orange
```

As you'll note there are four possible variable combinations: (store,apple), (online,apple), (store,orange), (online,orange). I'd like to assign a dummy variable column. My naive approach creates four dummy variables, whereas I want a single label column:

```py
pd.get_dummies(df,['location','item'])
>>>

location_online location_store  item_apple  item_orange
0   0   1   1   0
1   1   0   1   0
2   0   1   0   1
3   1   0   0   1
4   1   0   0   1
```

Whereas I'd prefer it to look like:

```
df 
>>>
location    item   combination     dummy
0   store   apple  (store, apple)   0
1   online  apple  (online, apple)  1
2   store   orange (store, orange)  2
3   online  orange (online, orange) 3
4   online  orange (online, orange) 3
```

Note, the dummy only equals the index because there are only 4 rows. This obviously would not be universally true.

Edit1: Above edited in response to comment.
Edit2: I've added a 5th row to illustrate that a row can be repeated, however, it should have the same dummy/combination as its duplicate.

Comment: Which pairs dummies go with?You want for example online-orange to be paired with 3 etc?

Comment: Why can't you use index itself?

Comment: @student, no for the reason I mentioned. What if there are more than 4 rows?

Comment: nevermind, just saw the edit to question.

Comment: @IoaTzimas, good point! I've added a column for combination name. However, a dictionary would work, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try `agg`:

```
df['combination'] = df[['location','item']].agg(tuple, axis=1)
df['dummy'] = df['combination'].factorize()[0]
```

Output:

```
  location    item       combination  dummy
0    store   apple    (store, apple)      0
1   online   apple   (online, apple)      1
2    store  orange   (store, orange)      2
3   online  orange  (online, orange)      3
4   online  orange  (online, orange)      3
```

If you don't care about `combination`, you can use `groupby.ngroup()`:

```
df['dummy'] = df.groupby(['location','item'], sort=False).ngroup()
```

Output:

```
  location    item  dummy
0    store   apple      0
1   online   apple      1
2    store  orange      2
3   online  orange      3
4   online  orange      3
```

Comment: @IoaTzimas Updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Let's create `combinations` by concatenating `location` and `item` then use `factorize` to encode these combinations to get `dummy` variables:

```
df['combination'] = df['location'].add(', ' + df['item'])
df['dummy'] = df['combination'].factorize()[0]
```

---

```
  location    item     combination  dummy
0    store   apple    store, apple      0
1   online   apple   online, apple      1
2    store  orange   store, orange      2
3   online  orange  online, orange      3
4   online  orange  online, orange      3
```

Comment: Awesome! Appears to be faster than by using the .apply() method. .add() might be vectorized...? (which would be great!)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a lambda function on first 2 columns. See below. d is a dictionary with dummies per pair.

```
d={('store', 'apple'):0, ('online', 'apple'):1, ('store', 'orange'):2, ('online', 'orange'):3}

def f(x,y):
    return d[(x,y)]

df['dummy'] = df[['location','item']].apply(lambda x: f(*x), axis=1)

>>>print(df)
  location    item  dummy
0    store   apple      0
1   online   apple      1
2    store  orange      2
3   online  orange      3
4   online  orange      3
```